# Bulk fix Album artwork in iTunes library for display on a Squeezebox Controller

Tags: itunes, album-art

This may actually be two questions in one. I've recently bought a Logitech Squeezebox Duet and as a result have noticed that a large amount of the album artwork in my iTunes library is either missing or just completely wrong.

So firstly is there an application that will perform a mass/bulk download of artwork for an iTunes library.

Secondly the controller handset for the Duet displays the album art for the track that is currently playing (and thumbnails of album art when browsing). For quite a few albums that do have correct artwork in iTunes, the art doesn't show up on the Squeezebox controller.

Answer (score 2):

I write a tool called [bliss](https://www.blisshq.com) that is intended for mass organisation of the album art for large music collections. It will download art that is missing, save it to a file, embed/not embed as required. I hope it helps you.

---

I hope posting this is acceptable by the rules of superuser - I looked in the faq/meta but couldn't find anything specific.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with it, but I recently saw an ad for [Tune-Up](http://www.tuneupmedia.com/). They have free and paid versions for PC and Mac.

Comment: I use Tune Up and like it. The free version is mostly worthless and the album artwork isn't terribly accurate, but the metadata cleanup is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, iTunes stores some artwork in its library database, and puts some in the meta tags on your files.  Your Duet should be able to display any artwork from a file's tags, but won't display artwork in the iTunes database.

I found a [post on AVforums](http://www.avforums.com/forums/streamers-network-music-players/847646-squeezebox-duet-artwork-missing.html) that mentions that the Duet will check two places for artwork:

1. The file's tags, and
2. The folder the file resides in, for files named `folder.jpg`, `album.jpg`, `thumb.jpg`, or `cover.jpg`.

I believe any tool that will scan your library files and download the cover art to either the folder or the tags will work for fixing artwork in the Duet.